# change value in column of df based on the index of another vector in R

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this

```
x1 <- rep(1,10)
x2 <- rep(2,10)
period[1:10] <- c(1.03304364774925, 1.22850285601178, 1.46094433717037, 1.73736540038594, 
  2.06608729549851, 2.45700571202355, 2.92188867434074, 3.47473080077187, 
  4.13217459099701, 4.91401142404711)

df <- rbind(x1, x2)
```

What I'm looking to do is replace the value of df[1] with the value in index 1 of period.

So `if df[1] == 1 #change to period[1]`

```
if df[2]==2 #change to period[2]
```

...etc. In reality, df[1:65] is = 1 and df[66:70] is = 2.

In the real data, the numbers in the `df` go from 1 to 65 and period is a vector of length 65.

I've tried some for loops like:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[1] <- 1/period[i]
}
```

but obviously after 65, you get just `NA`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can raise the quality of your question by correcting the errors in your example and cleaning up the explanation by providing the output that should result.

Comment: What do you mean by `df[1]`? Your `df` object has two dimensions, so should have two indexing arguments (even if one is blank).  If using a vector `vec <- sample.int(10, 10)` then you can do `vec2 <- period[vec]` or in your second example `vec2 <- 1/period[vec]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the column from the data frame as an index to the vector

```
df[,1]=period[df[,1]]
```

Comment: This is assuming that in your question you intended to create a single column dataframe. `df = data.frame(x=c(x1,x2))`